# Can we apply feature scaling to "independent variable" in a dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science

I have a dataset with 8 dependent variables (2 categorical data). I have applied `ExtraTreeClassifier()` to eliminate some of dependent variables.
I had also feature scale the X,y .

```
 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
 sc = StandardScaler()
 X = sc.fit_transform(X)
 X = sc.transform(X)
 y = sc.fit_transform(y)
 y = sc.transform(y)
```

And after this I have split the dataset like

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_new, encoded2, 
test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)
```

And now I am applying `DecisionTreeRegressor` algorithm for prediction.
But I want to the actual prediction (right now I am getting scaled value).
How to do that?
Is there any other approach to do it?
Because the way I have done is giving RMSE = 0.02 and if I am not feature scaling dependent variable RMSE = 18.4.
Please suggest how to solve this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, scaling your target variables (`y`) isn't required but if you do scale it, `StandardScaler` and various other such preprocessing techniques have an `inverse_transform` function through which you can get your original values.

From the documentation of [`StandardScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler):

> `inverse_transform(X[, copy])`    Scale back the data to the original representation

Comment: So if I use inverse_transform() on y_pred (predicted value) , do it will give the original value(not scaled one ) ??